# Как получить полный список команд Emacs с шорткатами

Tags: emacs

У меня возникло ощущение что они у меня отличаются от стандартных

Comment: Может ты не emacs скачал а ErgoEmacs? Там переделаны шоткаты

Comment: Я скачал оригинальный гнутый эмакс, но вопрос не в этом. А в том что хочется знать какие команды вообще есть и как их вызвать.

Comment: C-h r Вызывает Emacs Manual. Там разные команды разбиты по разделам. Или через меню Help -> Read Emacs Manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Список команд с шорткатами можно получить по `M-x describe-bindings` или `C-h b`

Источник https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbf

Comment: А  полный список команд (функций) IMHO проще всего получить, набрав `C-h f <TAB>`. Список появляется в буфере `*Completions*`. Кликнув мышкой в команду получаете ее описание (с текущими bindings).